# How do I write an integration test for openai's node SDK with streaming: true using jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, integration-testing, openai-api

I am having difficulty writing a test for openai's node.js SDK using the `streaming: true` flag.

The code that follows works great in the browser, I just wish to write a test for it.

I would like to test my whole express route, intercepting the call to openai, and have the execution continue in my own code. But I cannot for some reason intercept it/provide the correct response back to my own code from the mock.

I am not required to use any of the mocking libaries you see used in my code. So feel free to suggest alternatives.

```
it("should return stream the ai output if this is the first time fetching the document", async () => {
      nock("https://api.openai.com")
        .post("/v1/chat/completions")
        .reply(200, {
          id: "chatcmpl-123",
          object: "chat.completion.chunk",
          created: 1694268190,
          model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
          system_fingerprint: "fp_44709d6fcb",
          choices: [
            {
              index: 0,
              delta: {
                role: "assistant",
                content: "I am actually not OpenAI.",
              },
            },
          ],
          finish_reason: "stop",
        });
      const response = await agent.get(`${baseRoute}/documents/${documentId}`);
      expect(response.status).toBe(200);
      console.log(response.body);
    });
```

This is the /api/v2/documents/:id controller

```
const stream = await openaiService.getCompletionStream(document);
response.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
response.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
for await (const chunk of stream) {
  const data = chunk.choices[0]?.delta?.content;
  if (data !== undefined) {
    response.write(data);
  }
}

response.end();
```

This is the getCompletionStream function that gets called

```
getCompletionStream = async (document: DocumentDtoV2) => {
    const openai = this.getOpenAiAgent();
    const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: document.aiEngine.defaultProperties.model,
      messages: document.messages,
      max_tokens: document.aiEngine.defaultProperties.max_tokens,
      stream: true,
      temperature: document.prompt.model.customProperties.temperature
        ? document.prompt.model.customProperties.temperature
        : document.aiEngine.defaultProperties.temperature,
      top_p: document.prompt.model.customProperties.top_p
        ? document.prompt.model.customProperties.top_p
        : document.aiEngine.defaultProperties.top_p,
      frequency_penalty: (document.aiEngine.defaultProperties as ChatGPTProperties)
        .frequency_penalty,
      presence_penalty: (document.aiEngine.defaultProperties as ChatGPTProperties).presence_penalty,
    });

    return completion;
  };
```

Comment: Hey, did you get a chance to write integration test. i am running into same issue?

Comment: @PUG I did not as of yet. I might look into it next month again.